# Converting webp to png with .NET in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, file-format, webp

So, I have a webp image bytes which I get from decoding base 64 string, but the thing is that Unity can not understand webp Images, so I have changed Unitys default .NET 2.1 to .NET Framework 4.x to get access to the System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Imaging libraries I was hoping to use for image conversion. I have tried a lot of different ways to do this, but not a sigle one has worked so far.

Here are my attempts at converting the image from webp format to png

1. So, at first I was trying to use this method I found online to change the image format to png, but it gave me this Invalid Parameter error. [image: first error]

```
    private Texture2D baseToTex(string base64)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1); //Texture setup

        string b64_string = base64;
        byte[] b64_bytes_webp = System.Convert.FromBase64String(b64_string);

        byte[] b64_bytes_png = RewriteBytesToPng(b64_bytes_webp);

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.png", b64_bytes_png);
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.png");

        tex.LoadImage(bytes); //Load and apply Texture from bytes
        tex.Apply();
        return tex;
    }

    private byte[] RewriteBytesToPng(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var imageStream = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(inStream);
            imageStream.Save(outStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return outStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

2. Then I tried to do this the more straight forward way, like this

```
    private Texture2D baseToTex(string base64)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1); //Texture setup

        string b64_string = base64;
        byte[] b64_bytes_webp = System.Convert.FromBase64String(b64_string);

        var stream = new MemoryStream(b64_bytes_webp);
        Image img = new Bitmap(stream);
        img.Save(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.png");

        tex.LoadImage(bytes); //Load and apply Texture from bytes
        tex.Apply();
        return tex;
    }
```

This one didn't work either giving out pretty much the same error. [image: second error]
3. And for the third time I tried something rather different converting it like this

```
    private Texture2D baseToTex(string base64)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1); //Texture setup

        string b64_string = base64;
        byte[] b64_bytes_webp = System.Convert.FromBase64String(b64_string);

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.webp", b64_bytes_webp);

        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.webp"))
        {
            Image img = new Bitmap(image);
            img.Save(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\\Users\Limofeus\Desktop\img.png");

        tex.LoadImage(bytes); //Load and apply Texture from bytes
        tex.Apply();
        return tex;
    }
```

And this time I got an even stranger error, suggesting that I dont have enough memory for this operation [image: third error]

So, is there even a way to convert a webp to png with .NET? And if so, how do I implement it?

Comment: Part of the problem is that your file paths are double-escaped: use **either** `@"C:\Users\etc"` or `"C:\\Users\\etc"` - not both (i.e. don't use `'\\'` in `@""`-strings).